# JSon Parse from Wiki

Tags: android

Hello guys how can I parse wikipedia description, I don't need title or content I just need short description of wiki page. So I'm to parser but there is an error;

```
private static String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=chocolate";

//names
final String QUERY = "query";
final String LIST = "search";
final String TITLE = "title";
final String SNIPPET = "snippet";

JSONObject searchJson = new JSONObject(searchJsonStr);
JSONObject queryObject = searchJson.getJSONObject(QUERY);
JSONArray searchObject = queryObject.getJSONArray(LIST);
JSONObject titObject = (JSONObject) searchObject.get(0);

String title = titObject.getString(TITLE);
String description = titObject.getString(SNIPPET);
```

My error is;

> searchJsonStr cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: could you show the code when `searchJsonStr` gets initialized?

Comment: Actually I found this code in stackoverflow but there is no searchJsonStr, how can I do it?

Comment: This is not the way to ask questions...

Comment: Biz türkçe de anlaşırız Murat hocam :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because there's not any variable named searchJsonStr in your code.

You need to retrieve the JSON content of the api request first, and then use it as the variable searchJsonStr.

You can use this code for example:

```
String searchJsonStr = null;

URL url = new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&srsearch=chocolate");

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    searchJsonStr = getStringFromInputStream(in);
} else {
    searchJsonStr = null;
}
```

Comment: Actually I found this code in stackoverflow but there is no searchJsonStr, how can I do it?

Comment: I've modified mi answer to show you an examplo of how to fetch the JSON from the API